# How to make scrollable tabpanel in Extjs 4.1?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I created a tabpanel inside a window. I could use `autoScroll:true` with the window, but not with the tabpanel. I need it to work with tabpanel so when I scroll down, list of tabs won't go up and disappear.

Tabpanel:

```
 var   sections = Ext.createWidget('tabpanel', {
    id: 'mytabpanel',
    title: 'UM',
    activeTab: 3,
    closable: true,
    autoScroll: true, // not working
   //defaults:{ autoScroll:true }, //not working

    items: [
    {
```

Window (tabpanel container):

```
var window = new Ext.Window({
            id: 'item1',
            closable: true,
            floating: true,
            collapsible: true,
            width: 900,
            height: 600,
            autoScroll: true, //working
        items  : mytabpanel

}).show();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always specify the layout for a parent container. In this case your window component should have `layout: 'fit'` config.

Walk through examples to see how things are done in ExtJS. The guides are a must read for someone who is just starting out.

EDIT:
To your related question about inside scrolling issues: Take a look a this fiddle that is changed over from your original post - http://jsfiddle.net/REtRQ/3/ It shows the nested tab panel in the window. Please take a look at the use of `Ext.define` methods used to define your components before they are actually used.  This allows you clean code separation and does not force you to use global variables. Note how everything is name-spaced automatically.

Comment: well, something happens, I could scroll inside the tabpanel using mouse scroller. but on the laptop I don't know how to scroll.. the window is fixed and the scrollbar is useless.. did you had this problem?

Comment: no, you must have other setting or containers that need to be configured properly. without showing code I can not tell what else is happening. Why did you remove the Accepted mark?

Comment: Thanks, also please see the edits. I was answering your other question before you removed it.